How to run adb shell commands through flutter app?
I am trying CAN communication using Debix i.MX8 SBC with Android 11 installed. Am running a flutter app in which I need to run CAN(Controller Area Network) commands using adb shell.
Commands I need to run are:
 adb shell
 ifconfig can0 up

I used process_run dart package and tried the following.
  var shell = Shell();
  await shell.run("ifconfig can0 up");

But it is not working. It is throwing "ShellException(ifconfig can0 down, exitCode 1, workingDirectory: /)"
How to execute these shell commands through flutter application/using dart?

Are you talking about performing adb commands from within an Android app, or a Flutter app on PC side?

I want to run adb commands from flutter mobile app. Only for Android, not for other platforms. Android version is 11.

Android is not designed to allow access to adb fromwithin an app. There are some workarounds known where after each reboot you have to connect via USB  and enable adb tcp mode (adb tcpip 5555). Then you would have to include a cross-compiled adb binaries for the Android CPU architecture into your app and use them to connect voa TCP to the adbd on the same device.
